# Tkinter style not being applied

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm simply trying to change to "clam" style but nothing changes.  I have a more expansive UI written with other widgets, so I know that nothing changes when I try to change the style:

I'm working in Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.6.8, and using Pycharm.  I've verified that Pycharm is not the issue by running from terminal.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Style

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        self.master = master
        self.add_widgets()



    def add_widgets(self, ):
        self.mainframe = Frame(self.master, border=3)
        self.mainframe.grid(columnspan=3, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        Label(self.mainframe, text="Directory Selection", font='Helvetica 12 bold italic underline').grid(column=0, sticky="w")
        self.pathframe = Frame(self.mainframe, relief=RIDGE, border=2)
        self.pathframe.grid(rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky='w', padx=0, pady=10)


        button_color="dark gray";

        Button(self.pathframe, text="Run Folder Path", bg=button_color).grid(sticky="w")
        Entry(self.pathframe, width=43).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")



root = Tk()

style = Style()
style.theme_use("clam")


root.title('TestUI')
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I also tried:

```
style = Style(root)
style.theme_use("clam")
```

and still no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using any ttk widgets. The normal tkinter widgets aren't affected by the ttk styles.

Typically this is done by importing ttk and then prefixing the widgets with ttk

```
from tkinter import ttk
...
self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.master, border=3)
...
```